# Seeing vote counts on docs for users with >1000 rep

Tags: discussion, documentation

Should we let users with >1000 rep see vote counts on documentation? I don't support this change, but I'm not against this either. I want to see how the community reacts.

Comment: This is already [meta-tag:status-planned].

Comment: @JoshCaswell but the linked question says "This isn't implemented yet like it is in Q&A. It will make it eventually, but it's not officially on a roadmap (yet)."

Comment: Are you saying that this question is in reaction to that answer?

Comment: @JoshCaswell no.